# Compile Dart and Dartium on Debian 7

Tags: google-chrome, dart, google-chrome-devtools, dartium

I managed to compile Dart SDK in Debian and now I need to compile Dartium. I synced with the project and actually I got quite far after installing quite some amount of dev version libraries.

After that I got a Problem with Webkit compilation but got along since another tool was needed. But now I guess my moyo ran out. Here is the problem that I neither understand nor found a solution for on the web.

> ACTION crt_fini_32: build newlib x86-32 nlib_2010533c80fa84271e346fdfe3f57f1f
>   FAILED
>   FAILED: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>   [7/11319] CXX obj/chrome/gen/protoc_out/chrome/browser/feedback/proto/feedback_proto.chrome.pb.o
>   ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./dartium_tools/build.py", line 56, in module 
>       main()
>     File "./dartium_tools/build.py", line 53, in main
>       + targets)
>     File "/home/laptop/dartium/src/dartium_tools/utils.py", line 112, in runCommand
>       raise Exception('Failed to run command. return code=%s' % p.returncode)
>   Exception: Failed to run command. return code=1

PS: Is it normal that a 64bit OS tries to build a 32bit Dartium? I only found the Release / Debug switches but none for the 64bit version.

Comment: Could you post your process?  What commands did you invoke?  I've had good success following the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what's the reason for your specific issue but i can give you some general idea from my experience as to what was a stopper for me when i tried to build Dartium on Debian wheezy myself.

I can imagine you are trying to build dart-sdk and dartium  due to the glibc version mismatch. Although you are compiling dartium from source the build toolchain downloads many libraries & components precompiled with many of them also having a version mismatch issue with your glibc. **You will have to download each precompiled component that has a version mismatch separately and compile it yourself.**

I don't remember all the components that had an issue but i am sure ninja & native client both came precompiled with the wrong glibc version.

Regarding the 64bit Dartium, chromium currently only compiles to 32bit, same thing for dartium.

As an indirect answer your question, **if you are trying to build dart just so you can use it you are better off running Dart on a system that supports it out of the box**. Personally i have a virtual machine just for that, in the virtual machine you can either 1)run Ubuntu which comes with the correct glibc version (that's what Google uses to compile there builds)  2) install Debian testing which also comes with a newer gblic version that works or 3) Install Debian wheezy and only update glibc from testing repo (that's what i did)